# No me funcionan los modal de react-bootstrap

Tags: javascript, reactjs

aqui esta mi codigo, pero no me sale el modal, pero en el inspector si esta, pro favor alguien que me ayude.

```
function Example() {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

  const handleClose = () => setShow(false);
  const handleShow = () => setShow(true);

  return (
    <>
      <Button variant="primary" onClick={handleShow}>
        Launch demo modal
      </Button>

      <Modal show={show} onHide={handleClose}>
        <Modal.Header closeButton>
          <Modal.Title>Modal heading</Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body>Woohoo, you&apos;re reading this text in a modal!</Modal.Body>
        <Modal.Footer>
          <Button variant="secondary" onClick={handleClose}>
            Close
          </Button>
          <Button variant="primary" onClick={handleClose}>
            Save Changes
          </Button>
        </Modal.Footer>
      </Modal>
    </>
  );
}

render(<Example />);
```

Answer (score 0):

La [propiedad correcta](https://reactstrap.github.io/components/modals/) no es `show`, sino `isOpen`:

```
<Modal isOpen={show} onHide={handleClose}>
    ...
</Modal>
```

Como consejo, te puedo recomendar que manejes un solo evento para el *toggle* de tu modal, algo así:

```
const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
const toggleModal = () => setShow(!show);

return <>
    <Button variant="primary" onClick={toggleModal}>
        Launch demo modal
    </Button>

    <Modal isOpen={show} toggle={toggleModal}>
        ...
    </Modal>
</>
```